# nodejs addon Error: Unable to load shared library

Tags: c++, node.js

I have this simple code of node addon:

```
#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <class S>
class FooString
{
  protected:
    static std::vector< S > vec_strings;

  public:
    const S &str()  const {  return vec_strings[0]; }
    std::string tostdstring() const;
};

template <>
std::string FooString<std::string>::tostdstring() const {  return str();  }


namespace v8
{
  Handle<Value> Method(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;
    return scope.Close(String::New("world"));
  }

  void init(Handle<Object> target) {
    target->Set(String::NewSymbol("hello"),
      FunctionTemplate::New(Method)->GetFunction());
  }
  NODE_MODULE(test, init)
}
```

it compiles but when I'm runing script which including this addon:

```
var test = require('./build/Release/test');
console.log(test.hello()); // 'world'
```

I have got the error message:

```
node.js:199
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Unable to load shared library /home/run/git/addontest/build/Release/test.node
    at Object..node (module.js:474:11)
    at Module.load (module.js:350:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:356:17)
    at require (module.js:372:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/run/git/addontest/octonode.js:1:74)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:461:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:350:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
```

My g++ version is (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2 and nodejs version is v0.7.5-pre

could you check if you have any problems to compile and run this code?

Comment: And I'm assuming the file exists at that l0cation and has the right permissions?

Comment: @loganfsmyth yes, of course, it exists and has right permissions

Comment: @loganfsmyth Have you tried to run this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's not loving the fact that you haven't allocated space for your static variable anywhere.

Adding this fixes it for me.

```
template <class S>
std::vector< S > FooString<S>::vec_strings;
```